# Get the formating lines vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hey i was just wondering how to enable (or get) lines that mark the formating in vscode ?

[image]

Something like so :

[image]

Comment: they are screenshots using different themes

Comment: It's just about the theme ? Well my bad then i though it was an option ^^

Comment: you mark the tags but not the lines, search the settings for **guides**